# cannot to connect to X server

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I would like to run script (python) from my phone by bluetooth.
I have an app when I can see the shell of my Raspberry PI3. 
Actually the problem, I can't run any script. I got always sometimes this error :

```
Cannot connect to X server
```

or this : `Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?`

But I do not want to connect my RPI3 or my phone by Wifi. Only Bluetooth.

So is it possible to have full acess to the shell for run script python ?

I use this code source : http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2015/11/android-bluetooth-terminal.html

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Probably need to post some code if you want help, not totally clear on requirements

Answer (score 0):

Because that your Python script is used GUI, so it needs X server.

There are some apps like X server for android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.org.server

But serial connection by bluetooth is too slow, so I think you need WiFi connection.

Comment: I finally found yesterday, I used simply : DISPLAY=:0 python name.py